# Problems with default font

Tags: fonts, formatting

I want to change the default fonts. I followed the guide: [https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces#:~:text=the%20example%20above%3A-,Changing%20default%20font%20typeface,specific%20element%20in%20the%20document.&text=The%20command%20%5Cfontfamily%7Bqcr%7D%5C,the%20text%20inside%20the%20braces](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces#:%7E:text=the%20example%20above%3A-,Changing%20default%20font%20typeface,specific%20element%20in%20the%20document.&text=The%20command%20%5Cfontfamily%7Bqcr%7D%5C,the%20text%20inside%20the%20braces).

However, it is really weird that only “tgbonum” works, but "tgadventor" font does not.

I want to know how to easily change the default font for the list of fonts.

Here is the full premeable code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[sfdefault]{universalis}
\linespread{2}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{comment}
\everymath{\color{blue}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{cancel}
\definecolor{FigBlue}{rgb}{0.150,0.60,0.80}
\definecolor{BubBlue}{rgb}{0.35,0.8,1.00}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{rgb}{0.175,0.4,0.5}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new PDF window
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=red,          % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
    citecolor=blue,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links
}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
%sorting=ynt
sorting=nyt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{name.bib}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[section] 
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{condition}{Condition}
\newtheorem{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem*{hypothesis*}{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{structural assumption}{Structural Assumption}
\newtheorem*{proposition*}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} [section]
\newcommand{\FX}{\mathbb{P}^X}
\newcommand{\pspace}{(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})}
%\newcommand{\reals}{\mathscr{R}}
\newcommand{\rats}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\bzero}{\boldsymbol{0}}
\newcommand{\ba}{\boldsymbol{a}}
\newcommand{\bp}{\boldsymbol{p}}
\newcommand{\bA}{\boldsymbol{A}}
\newcommand{\bx}{\boldsymbol{x}}
\newcommand{\bX}{\boldsymbol{X}}
\newcommand{\bY}{\boldsymbol{Y}}
\newcommand{\bDelta}{\boldsymbol{\Delta}}
\newcommand{\bZ}{\boldsymbol{Z}}
\newcommand{\bSigma}{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}
\newcommand{\btheta}{\boldsymbol{\theta}}
\newcommand{\reals}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\diff}{{\rm d}}
\newcommand{\Fn}{\mathcal{F}_n}
\newcommand{\dP}{{\rm d}\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\pconverge}{\overset{p}{\longrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\dconverge}{\overset{\mathcal{D}}{\longrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\convP}{\overset{\mathscr{P}}{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\convW}{\overset{w}{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\convas}{\overset{\rm a.s.}{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\myp}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\diag}[1]{{\rm \mathbf{Diag}}\myp{#1}}
\newcommand{\cexp}[1]{\mathbb{E}(#1|\mathcal{G})}
\newcommand{\expect}[1]{\mathscr{E}{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\idfun}[1]{\mathbf{1}_{\{#1\}}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left|#1\right|}
\newcommand{\pq}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert #1\rVert}
\newcommand{\mycomments}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\mathbf{Var}{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\prob}[1]{\mathscr{P}{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\cov}[1]{\mathbf{Cov}{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\argmin}[1]{\mathbf{\rm argmin\:}{#1}}
\newcommand{\nd}[1]{{\rm N}\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\infor}[1]{\mathscr{F}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\convLp}[1]{\overset{\mathscr{L}^#1}{\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\conexp}[2]{\mathscr{E}\left[\left.#1\right|#2\right]}
\newcommand{\normdist}[2]{\sim\mathscr{N}\left(#1,#2\right)}
\newcommand{\pref}{\succcurlyeq}
\newcommand{\RDU}[1]{{\rm RDU}\left(#1\right)}
\newenvironment{solution}
{\let\oldqedsymbol=\qedsymbol
    \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacktriangleleft$}
    \begin{proof}[\bfseries\upshape Solution]}
    {\end{proof}
    \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\oldqedsymbol}}

%\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
```

Comment: You are loading to many packages (some more than once) including various conflicting packages that change the font. clean up your preamble.